# Starting apache2 starts three processes

Tags: server, apache2

I would like to know why the command to start apache2 server actually starts three processes

Indeed, typing this command:

```
sudo apache2ctl -k start
```

then, typing this command:

```
ps aux | grep apache2
```

gives three processes corresponding to apache2.
Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Apache has several different processing modules to handle requests. The most common ones are `worker` and `prefork`. Both use multiple processes. `Prefork` uses a process per client connection and always makes sure that there are a few idle processes available to handle new connections without delay. `Worker` still uses several processes but also uses threads in these processes. This uses fewer resources compared to `prefork` but still needs several processes normally.

One process you see is probably the "master" process which opens the TCP ports and waits for connections and passes incoming connections to a different apache process to do the actual processing. The other processes are worker processes, either from `prefork` or `worker` module.